# Define custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I wanna learn **how to define a custom event**, but not exactly as it is said over the net! let me illustrate:

In the jQuery Website in the part **[Introducing Custom Events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)** it teaches you how to create a custom event in your code:

***e.g.***

```
$(document).on('myEvent',function(){
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

then on an event, you'll call:

```
$(document).trigger('myEvent');
```

Well, no problem until here. to go further I have to give you another example:

***The Question:***

let's say we've defined:

```
$.fn.myEvent=function(callback){
    $(document).bind('contextmenu',this,callback);
};
```

so we can use it as:

```
$(document).myEvent(function(){
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

my question here is, how can we define **"myEvent"** so that we can use it as:

```
$(document).on('myEvent',function(){
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

with the functionality of the `$(document).myEvent();` so that we can pass a callback function to it without needing to actually `trigger` the event?

***More Explanation:***

for example, when we call `$(document).on('click');` we don't actually need to trigger the click event elsewhere like `$(document).trigger('click')` in order to get it to work, so whenever `click` happens the function fires. I wanna have an event listener for **"myEvent"** so that when the conditions are matched, the function fires.

In another word (as mentioned below in the comments), I wanna know if there's a way to let jQuery treat **"myEvent"** as if it is one of the default events (click, mousemove, submit, etc).

Any answer or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Which conditions need to be satisfied in order for myEvent to fire?

Comment: Your `myEvent` is a custom event, it will never happen in the wild unless you make it happen by triggering it, so what exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: @JeffN the condition (as an example) is `contextmenu` (or if the user right clicks on the page)

Comment: But that isn't `myEvent`, it's the `contextmenu` event, this really makes no sense ?

Comment: @adeneo I wanna know if there's a way to let jQuery treat it as if it is one of the default events

Comment: @adeneo it can be whatever makes sense to you, `contextmenu` is just a short-handed example! you can change it to on press of the enter key if that'll make sense

Comment: To answer your question, there's no way to make a custom event act like a native event, closest you'll get is triggering it with something like `$(document).on('contextmenu', function() { $(document).trigger('myEvent') });`

Comment: @adeneo well, good to know, thank you for your response, I appreciate it ;)

Comment: the last code block is correct, there's just nothing to invoke it by default like there is for click(), contextmenu(), etc. you can just name a function that invokes myEvent's callback, and pass it to lots of triggers at once ala   $("body").on("click,mousedown,contextmenu", fnRaiseMyEvent )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who are wondering (like I did in the last 2 years) you can create a custom event (using pure javascript) as explained below:

```
var myEvent = new Event('myEvent');
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener(myEvent, function () {});
```

**Simple Usage Example**  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1gbrLndd/2/)**

Let's say we have a variable called `bgColor` and we want to change background color of 5 buttons, color of a paragraph and border color of an input anytime the `bgColor` value changes AND we don't want to use an interval to check on the value change and we also don't want to repeat the same code over and over again anytime the variable changes.

First we need to define our variables:

```
var bgColor='red',
    eventName = 'bgColorChanged';
```

Then we need to listen for the event:

```
function Listen(elems,eventName,callback){

    var event=new Event(eventName); //create the custom event

    for(var i=0, elemsLength=elems.length; i < elemsLength; i++){ //iterate over the selected elements

        elems[i].addEventListener(event,callback); //add event listener for our custom event

        elems[i][eventName]=event; //store the event

        //store the element
        if(window.affectedElems){
            window.affectedElems.push(elems[i])
        }
        else{
            window.affectedElems=[];
            window.affectedElems.push(elems[i])
        }
        //----------------------------

    }
}
```

Now we can listen for our custom event like this:

```
Listen(document.querySelectorAll('button'),eventName,function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor=bgColor;
});
```

Then we need a function to Dispatch/Fire our Event:

```
function dispatchEvent(eventName) {

    var event=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"), //defining the type of the event

    elems=window.affectedElems; //getting the stored elements

    //iterating over each element and dispatching the stored event
    for(var i=0, elemsLength=elems.length; i < elemsLength; i++){
        event.initEvent(elems[i][eventName], true, true);
        event.eventName = eventName;
        elems[i].dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    //-----------------------------------
}
```

Now we can fire our event like this:

```
dispatchEvent(eventName);
```

Now that everything's ready we just need to change the value of `bgColor` and just fire the event and let our system do the work.

```
bgColor='blue';
dispatchEvent(eventName);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I wanna have an event listener for "myEvent" so that when the conditions are matched, the function fires.

How would the engine know what "conditions" you mean? No, "custom events" are called *custom* because they are not *natively* trigged (through some lower-level action), but by custom code.
You *may* trigger a custom event whenever *you* see the condition matched that you're looking for.

About the definition of `$.fn.myEvent`, you might want to have a look at [how the shortcuts for native events are created](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click) (where `name` would be `"myEvent"`).

Comment: very interesting source you shared! +1

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, [here's the whole snippet](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L6) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're lumping together two different points:

1. how events work on general, and
2. *how a browser environment dispatches events* related to user action.

For the first point, I'll quote from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280380/710446):

> In JavaScript, a custom event is simply a message, broadcast to all event listeners, that says, "Attention everyone: event X just happened!" Any listener that cares about that event can then run some function.

That's how events work in JavaScript. You set up listeners, and later something triggers the event. The trigger acts as a message to the listeners, telling them to run.

I've just said *something* triggers an event: we'll call that thing the *initiator* of the event. With custom events, the initiator is always other JavaScript code that you write (or that comes from a library, etc.). However, with native events the initiator is the *browser itself*. There is no way for JavaScript to control how the browser chooses to dispatch events.

The best you can do is listen for native browser events and then have those listeners dispatch custom events themselves.